# ffmpeg: Spliting video but keeping the timestamp

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to split a part of a video into a mpegts. My issue is that the start_pts is not 0 even if i use -copyts 
The original stremas looks like this : 
Audio & Video :

```
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
```

The generated file loogs like this : 
Video :

```
start_pts=133508
start_time=1.483422
duration_ts=450449
duration=5.004989
```

Audio :

```
start_pts=131588
start_time=1.462089
duration_ts=445440
duration=4.949333
```

The command used :

```
-loglevel debug  -i video.mkv -ss 0.00 -profile:v  high -to 5.00 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -pix_fmt yuv420p  -copyts -f mpegts test0.ts
```

My question is why the start_pts is not zero ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`ffmpeg -loglevel debug -copyts -i video.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -ss 0.00 -to 5.00 -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -c:a aac -muxpreload 0 -muxdelay 0 -f mpegts test0.ts`

MPEG-TS is a streaming format and ffmpeg will offset timestamps to accommodate possible video encoding delay. Setting muxpreload and muxdelay to 0 can avoid that.

Comment: it worked a little better but still not perfect 
Video :
`avg_frame_rate=24000/1001
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=7508
start_time=0.083422
duration_ts=450449
duration=5.004989 `

Audio: 
`time_base=1/90000
start_pts=5588
start_time=0.062089
duration_ts=453075
duration=5.034167
bit_rate=7875`

There is also a difference between audio and video.

Comment: Also, if i change the -ss to 5, and -to 10, then the start time should be 5 , duration 5 , but that is not what is happening. If i let the muxdeplay then it says again 0.062.. , if i remove it then start times is again `start_time=1.462089`